# What exactly does fakepow option do in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

If you use '--fakepow option' in geth, what exactly happens?

The [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) in Geth says:

> --fakepow Disables proof-of-work verification

Does it create a block without PoW? or does it skip the block verification?

And what is this option for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This flag was added in commit [#2485](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2485), entitled:

> "Add a `--fakepow` flag to help benchmarking database changes".

From the description on the PR, it:

> ...allows testing and evaluating various non POW related optimizations
>   by themselves (e.g. database opts) without having to constantly wait
>   for the costly POWs to also run.

Comment: This does not answer the question of the OP
>Does it create a block without PoW?

Comment: But isn't the answer to that (sub-question) implicitly "no"? :) The main question asks what the flag does.

Comment: Actually, @richa